# Prove Cauchy criterion without using the bounded property

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

The **Cauchy criterion** states that:

```
A sequence is Cauchy if and only if it converges.
```

Almost all proofs I can find for this theorem use the fact that:

```
A Cauchy sequence is bounded.
```

However, both the definitions of Cauchy sequence and converged sequence only use the ***metric*** of the system, which gives the distance between elements. While *bounded property*  measures the elements themselves, use the ***norm*** of the system.

It is true that we may define consistent ***metric*** and ***norm***. However, it is not necessary. Thus why we need the 'extra' norm to prove a statement only involves ***metric***?

The question is: if a sequence (either Cauchy or Converged) comes from a set that only defining ***metric*** (and the metric may not satisfy *translation invariance*, thus it can not induce a ***norm***, so that we can not use it to give the *bounded property* of a Cauchy sequence),
can we still prove the **Cauchy criterion**?

Comment: Are you saying that the property of boundedness requires the metric space to be normed? If so, then that's not true.

Comment: You can think of the statement "is bounded" as "is contained inside a ball", which is a metric statement.

Comment: @DIdier_ Yes, right, thank you. So that "$d(a_n,0)\leq d(A,0)$ is satisfied  for all $a_n$" means  the sequence is **bounded** by $A$.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write $d(a_n,0) < A$ (recall that a distance is a real valued function!) but yes, you got the idea

Comment: @DIdier_  Yes. Also, $0$ is not necessarily an element. Should be $d(a_n,a_m)\leq A$ for any $a_n,a_m$.

Comment: No, I meant, the sequence $(a_n)$ of elements of $(E,d)$  is bounded if there exists a point $p\in E$ and a positive number $r>0$ such that: $\forall n, d(p,a_n) <r$. This means that all $a_n$ live in the same ball $B(p,r)$. Also, I think you are mentionning the proof that $\mathbb{R}$ equiped with the absolute value distance is complete. It is not complete forsome  other distances, even if it can be bounded.

Comment: @DIdier_ Get it. the open ball definition is great. Is it OK to use my local compare $d(a_n,a_m)$ to show bounded property?  I dont go that far about complete. Can you give me a simple example of metric, which makes  $\mathbb{R}$  bounded  but not complete (a link is also good).

Comment: In fact, a first property of Cauchy sequences is that they remain inside a ball with center $a_0$. The radius can be large.

In $\mathbb{R}$, $d(x,y)= |\mathrm{arctan}x-\mathrm{arctan}y|$ is a distance but is not complete, as the sequence of integers is Cauchy but do no converges.